# Questions on multi-controlled Toffolis and their implementation in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, transpile

1. Is it possible to decompose an $n$-controlled Toffoli into $O(n)$ CNOTs without extra working qubits?
2. If so, is such an decomposition currently available in Qiskit or any other (preferably Python and QASM-friendly) packages?

If not:

3. Has such an impossibility been proven?
4. Is *any* decomposition into $O(n)$ CNOTs available in Qiskit or any other (preferably Python and QASM-friendly) packages?

In 2022, neither 2 nor 4 haven't apparently been implemented yet in Qiskit, see "**Implemented by Qiskit**:" [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-031-08760-8_16).

**UPDATE**

Using the following `tket` code (suggested in the answer below)

```
import qiskit
from pytket.extensions.qiskit import qiskit_to_tk, tk_to_qiskit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pytket.transform as tkt

N = 10
qcs = []
cnots = []
x = np.array( range(1,145,9) )
for i,n in enumerate(x):
    qc = qiskit.QuantumCircuit(n+1)
    qc.mcx( list( range( n ) ), n )
    # print(qc)
    c = qiskit_to_tk( qc )
    tkt.Transform.CnXPairwiseDecomposition().apply( c )
    qc = tk_to_qiskit( c )
    # print(qc)
    if 'cx' not in qc.count_ops(): # At one value of n, instead of CX, controlled RX are produced
        qc = qiskit.transpile( qc, basis_gates = [ 'u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'cx' ] )
    cnot = qc.count_ops()[ 'cx' ]
    print( f'Step {i+1}/{len( x )}; {n} qubits; {cnot} CNOTs' )
    qcs.append( qc )
    cnots.append( cnot )

fig, axs = plt.subplots( 1, 2 )
fig.suptitle( 'CNOTs' )
fig.set_size_inches( 10, 5 )
axs[ 0 ].plot( x, cnots, label = 'CNOTs')
axs[ 0 ].plot( x, x, label = 'x' )
axs[ 0 ].plot( x, 4*x*x, label = '4*x^2' )
axs[ 0 ].plot( x, 200*x, label = '200*x' )
axs[ 0 ].set_xlabel( 'n of control qubits' )
axs[ 0 ].set_ylabel( 'CNOTs' )
axs[ 0 ].legend()
axs[ 1 ].loglog( x, cnots, label = 'CNOTs' )
axs[ 1 ].loglog( x, x, label = 'x' )
axs[ 1 ].loglog( x, 4*x*x, label = '4*x^2' )
axs[ 1 ].loglog( x, 200*x, label = '200*x' )
axs[ 1 ].set_xlabel( 'n of control qubits' )
axs[ 1 ].set_ylabel( 'CNOTs' )
axs[ 1 ].legend()
plt.show()
```

gives

[image]

The cost is quadratic up to 50 (!!) control qubits and then seems to be linear. This happens because under 50 qubits the `tket` [function](https://github.com/CQCL/tket/blob/develop/tket/src/Transformations/Replacement.cpp#L58) `multi_controlled_to_2q()` calls function `CnU_linear_depth_decomp()` for simplifying multi-controlled gates, and above 50 it switches to using `CnX_normal_decomp()`. (They claim that this is the right way to do things — and the plot kinda suggests that this is indeed the case.)

What surprises/upsets me is the factor of 200 in the linear regime — [Craig Gidney's post](https://algassert.com/circuits/2015/06/05/Constructing-Large-Controlled-Nots.html) provides a solution with ~16n Toffolis, each of which can be represented by 6 CNOTs.

**UPDATE 2**

The implementation with $(n-2)$ (usual) ancillary qubits, as explained by Craig Gidney, requires $6(2n-3)=12n-18$ CNOTs, since each $n$-controlled gate is expanded into $(2n-3)$ Toffolis, each of which is decomposed into $6$ CNOTs:

[image]

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, transpile

def mcx_decomposed( qr_c: QuantumRegister,
                    qr_t: QuantumRegister,
                    qr_anc: QuantumRegister ) -> QuantumCircuit:
    """
    Decomposes the multi-controlled X gate into elementary gates.
    :param qr_c: Control registers
    :param qr_t: Target register
    :param qr_anc: Ancilla registers
    :return: Output circuit
    """
    n = len( qr_c )
    assert n >= 1, "The control register must contain at least one qubit."
    assert len( qr_t ) == 1, "The target register must contain a single qubit."
    assert n < 3 or len( qr_anc ) == n - 2, "The ancilla register must contain n - 2 qubits."

    qc = QuantumCircuit( qr_c, qr_t, qr_anc )

    if n == 1:
        qc.cx( qr_c[ 0 ], qr_t[ 0 ] )
    elif n == 2:
        qc.ccx( qr_c[ 0 ], qr_c[ 1 ], qr_t[ 0 ] )
        qc = transpile( qc, basis_gates = [ 'u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'cx' ] )
    else:
        qc.ccx( qr_c[ 0 ], qr_c[ 1 ], qr_anc[ 0 ] )
        for i in range( n - 3 ):
            qc.ccx( qr_anc[ i ], qr_c[ i + 2 ], qr_anc[ i + 1 ] )
        qc.ccx( qr_anc[ n - 3 ], qr_c[ n - 1 ], qr_t[ 0 ] )
        for i in range( n - 4, -1, -1 ):
            qc.ccx( qr_anc[ i ], qr_c[ i + 2 ], qr_anc[ i + 1 ] )
        qc.ccx( qr_c[ 0 ], qr_c[ 1 ], qr_anc[ 0 ] )

        qc = transpile( qc, basis_gates = [ 'u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'cx' ], optimization_level = 3 )
    return qc
```

To sum up:

- Without ancillas: $\approx 4n^2$ CNOTs for $n<50$, then $\approx 200n$ CNOTs.
- With $n-2$ ancillas: $12n-18$ CNOTs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to decompose an $n$-controlled Toffoli into $O(n)$ CNOTs without extra working qubits?

Yes! [This blog post series](https://algassert.com/circuits/2015/06/05/Constructing-Large-Controlled-Nots.html) by [Craig Gidney](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/119/craig-gidney) describe how to do that.

> If so, is such an decomposition currently available in Qiskit or any other (preferably Python and QASM-friendly) packages?

Form the code [here](https://github.com/CQCL/tket/blob/main/tket/src/Circuit/ControlledGates.cpp#L232), this method is implemented in tket. So, you can use it in Python with pytket.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!! No wonder he's a coauthor of [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.8.041015).

Comment: Please see the updated question.